# App Corner Not In Settings Menu

Tags: 8.1, lumia-635

I want to enable apps corner, but when I go to Settings it isn't there; it skips from VPN to Workplace. How do I get it on there?
Here is a ScreenShot:[image]

Comment: The system settings menu isn't in a fixed order. Have you looked through the entire list?